# Selenium Upgrade Error

Tags: java, selenium

I have made an extension which implements WebElement and a listener which implements WebDriverEventListener.

I was on Selenium 42 and trying to upgrade the library to selenium 53 in pom.xml. when I try to compile, i get the following compilation errors:

MyWebElement is not abstract and does not override abstract method    getRect() in org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

CustomWebDriverEventListener is not abstract and does not override    abstract method afterNavigateRefresh(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver)    in org.openqa.selenium.support.events.WebDriverEventListener

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that they have added methods to the WebElement WebDriverEventListener interfaces. You need to implement those methods in your classes.

So, you need to add an implementation of the getRect method even if it returns null (see https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getRect--)

```
Rectangle getRect()
```

For the WebDriverEventListener you need to implement the method afterNavigateRefresh.  See https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html#afterNavigateRefresh-org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver-

```
void afterNavigateRefresh(WebDriver driver)
```

You could also make your class abstract if you don't need to instantiate them.